# Can i return SQL procedure before committing the transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can i use return statement in a sql transaction procedure?

Sql Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProcessStudentRecord] 
AS 
Begin Transaction
insert into dbo.Student(name,address) values('ABC','INDIA'); 
return; 
Commit Transaction
```

Is it a good practice of writing return inside a Transaction?

Comment: The `commit` will never take place.

Comment: @gordonLinoff My query is working fine and even the  code is getting commit.that's why i am confused.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: Despite appearances, `BEGIN TRANSACTION .. COMMIT` is not a statement block. `BEGIN`, `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` can appear whenever you please, and the statements are executed in strict sequential fashion. Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql), "Statements that follow `RETURN` are not executed." Your transaction count should be off by one when exiting the stored procedure (requiring an additional `COMMIT`).

Comment: @Joe I have multiple condition in my query and if 1st condition satisfy ,i don't won't to execute  the whole procedure .(I can't use if else ladder).

Comment: `GOTO` is available in T-SQL. While generally frowned upon, using it only for forward jumps to an exit label is an acceptable way of using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a good practice of writing return inside a Transaction?

No. In fact you will get this SQL Server error and the transaction will remain uncommitted:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

When a transaction is started in a stored procedure, the best practice is to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` prior to returning. Also, it's a good practice to specify `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in procs with explicit transactions to avoid inadvertently leaving a transaction open after a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

rollback transaction will undo it. 
returning it will do nothing if you didn't commit it first.
But i do not see any point of doing what you are doing now in your statement unless you are going to use a try catch or some other statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do want to be able to commit even if the transaction is rolled back (and the only viable reason I can think of is for logging purposes) there are a couple of options open to you:

1. Use the Service Broker with event notifications [link](https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2010/10/17/logging-messages-during-a-transaction.aspx)
2. Use a linked server pointing back to same DB instance without distributed transaction promotion - this will commit in a completely isolated transaction.

But please first reconsider if this is something you really need to do!